# How does this function arrive while formulating the auxiliary inequality for proof of $\mathcal {L^p}$ as a metric space?

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

The metric for $\mathcal {L^p}$ space is defined by:
$$d(x,y)=\Big(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} {\lvert \xi_{j}-\eta_j\rvert}^p\Big)^\frac{1}{p}$$
where, $x,y \ \in \ \mathcal {L^p}$ and $x=(\xi_j), y= (\eta_j)$.

Now, all of the axioms are readily proved by this metric provided that we prove that the R.H.S. of the metric is convergent.

The book that I am following (cited below), follows some steps, to prove the convergence. The first step is to derive an auxiliary inequality where we prove that for, some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ $\in \ \mathbb {R^+}$  and for some $p$ and $q$ which are **conjugate exponents**, the following inequality hold true,
$$\alpha\beta \leq \frac{\alpha^p}{p} +\frac{\beta^q}{q}$$

Now, to prove this inequality the author assumes a function $u = t^{p-1}$ and with the help of this function, he proves the auxiliary inequality above.

$\bullet~$ *My question is, why do we assume this particular function?*

$\bullet~$ **References:**

1. Introductory functional analysis with applications - Erwin Kreyszig Pg. 12-13

Comment: "Now, all of the axioms are readily proved by this metric provided that we prove that the R.H.S. of the metric is convergent... The book that I am following (cited below), follows some steps, to prove the convergence."  The RHS is readily shown to be convergent.  The issue is proving that the metric satisfies the triangle inequality, which is not so readily proved.

Comment: $$\Big(\sum^{\infty}_{j=1} {\lvert \xi_{j}-\eta_j\rvert}^p\Big)^\frac{1}{p} \leq \Big(\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} {\lvert \xi_{k}\rvert}^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}} + \Big(\sum^{\infty}_{m=1} {\lvert \eta_{m}\rvert}^p\Big)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

Comment: I had in mind that we can use Minkowski Inequality to prove the convergence too, making it general.

Comment: Can you make your question more precise?  Is it about $\mathcal{L}^{p}$ or is it actually about Young's inequality?  The question "Why do we assume this function?" is very vague.

Comment: I apologise but I think, I have made it as precise as possible to my abilities. To prove the auxiliary inequality the author puts forward a function defined in the question and uses that in order to prove that inequality which in turn proves the remaining axiom of the Metric space i.e. The triangle I equality for $\mathcal{L^p}$.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality used in the context is *Young's Inequality.*

What you are speaking about is proving the inequality using a famous problem from **Putnam and Beyond**, namely

*Let $f : [0, r) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ be continuous and strictly increasing with $f(0) = 0$ (the case of $r = \infty$ is allowed). Show that for every $a$ in $[0, r)$ and every $b$ in image of $[0, r)$ under $f$, we have*
\begin{align*}
    ab \leqslant \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{b} f^{-1}(t) dt
\end{align*}

In which you want to plug in the function $f(x) = x^{p - 1}$, which satisfies all the conditions to proof the *Young's Inequality*.

However I know an extension of the inequality which also gives us some important results.

The use of this inequality is a required one in the proof of $``l^p-\textit{norm being a norm}"$ through some steps and **Lemmas**.

What I mean is, if we have the linear space $(X, \| \cdot \|_{p})$, then $\| \cdot \|_{p}$ is a norm in $X$ (Where $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{K}^n$, for $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{C}$).

$\bullet~$ **Target:** We will show using the *Young's Inequality* for the Hölder conjugate numbers $p, q$ $\in$ $(0, \infty)$, that $\| \cdot \|_{p}~$ is a norm.

$\bullet~$ **Prerequisites and Defn :** Let's consider the numbers $p, q$ $\in$ $(0, \infty)$ such that the following is satisfied.
$$ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $$
Then assume the *Young's Inequality* for some $a, b$ $\in$ $\mathbb{K},~$ with $a, b \geqslant {0}$.
$$ ab \leqslant \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^q}{q} $$
Take any $x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n}) \in \mathbb{K}^n $. Define $\| x\|_{p}$ and $\| x\|_{q}$ in the usual manner, i.e.,
$$ \| x\|_{p} = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lvert x_{i}\rvert^{p}} $$

$\bullet~$ **Lemma 1:** Consider $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{K}^n$. Suppose $\boldsymbol{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n})$ and $\boldsymbol{b} = (b_{1}, b_{2}, \dots, b_{n})$. Then the following holds
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lvert a_{k} b_{k} \rvert \leqslant \| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{q}  $$

$\bullet~$ *Proof:*

$\circ$ **Case (1):** The case with $\boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol{b} = \boldsymbol{0}$ is trivial.

$\circ$ **Case (2):** Let's consider $\| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} = \| \boldsymbol{b}\|_{q} = 1$. Then by *Young's Inequality* we have that
\begin{align*}
\lvert a_{i}b_{i} \rvert &\leqslant \frac{\lvert a_{i} \rvert^{p}}{p} + \frac{\lvert b_{i} \rvert^{q}}{q} \\
\implies \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert a_{i} b_{i} \rvert &\leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{\lvert a_{i} \rvert^{p}}{p} + \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{\lvert b_{i} \rvert^{q}}{q} = \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 = \| \boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_{q}
\end{align*}

$\circ$ **Case (3):** Let's assume neither of $~\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b}$ is $\boldsymbol{0},~$ nor $~\|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p}, \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{q} = 1 $.

Then let's pick $~\boldsymbol{x} = \dfrac{\boldsymbol{a}}{\|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p}}~$ and $~\boldsymbol{y} = \dfrac{\boldsymbol{b} }{\|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{q}}$. Note that $\| \boldsymbol{x} \|_{p} = \| \boldsymbol{y} \|_{q} = 1.~$ So by the argument in **Case (2)**, we have
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert x_{i} y_{i} \rvert \leqslant 1 \implies \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \frac{\lvert a_{i}b_{i} \rvert }{\| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} \cdot \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{q}} \leqslant 1 \implies \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert a_{i}b_{i} \rvert \leqslant \| \boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} \cdot \| \boldsymbol{b} \|_{q} $$

$\bullet~$ **Lemma 2:** Consider $\boldsymbol{a}, \boldsymbol{b} \in \mathbb{K}^n$ like before.
then the following holds

$\bullet~$ **(a)** $$\|\boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p}^{p} \leqslant \big( \|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \big)\cdot \|\boldsymbol{v} \|_{q} $$
Where $\boldsymbol{v} = \big((a_{1} + b_{1})^{p -1}, (a_{2} + b_{2})^{p - 1}, \dots, (a_{n} + b_{n})^{p - 1} \big)$

$\bullet~$ **(b)** The following inequality holds
$$ \|\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \leqslant \|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p}  $$

$\bullet~$ *Proof (a):* Let's consider $(a_{i} + b_{i})^{p - 1} = v_{i}$ and $\boldsymbol{v} = (v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3}, \dots, v_{n})$.

Then from **Lemma 1** we have that
\begin{align*}
\| \boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{b} \|_{p}^{p} =&~ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert (a_{i} + b_{i})^p \rvert \\
=&~\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\lvert (a_{i} + b_{i}) v_{i} \rvert \\
\leqslant&~ \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert a_{i} v_{i} \rvert + \sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lvert b_{i}v_{i} \rvert\\
\leqslant&~ \|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} \cdot \|\boldsymbol{v} \|_{q} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \cdot \|\boldsymbol{v} \|_{q}  \\
=&~ (\|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p}) \cdot \|\boldsymbol{v} \|_{q}
\end{align*}
Completing the proof.

$\bullet~$ *Proof (b):* Let $\boldsymbol{v}$ be the same as **Lemma 2 (a),** then from the relation of *Hölder's Conjugate Numbers* we have
$$ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 \implies q \cdot (p - 1) = p $$
Again we have that $$ (pq - q) = p \implies \bigg(p - \frac{p}{q}\bigg) = 1 $$
Now we have that $(a_{i} + b_{i})^{p - 1} = v_{i}.~$ Therefore we have that
$$ \| \boldsymbol{v}\|_{q}^{q} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} \lvert (a_{i} + b_{i})^{(p - 1)\cdot q} \rvert = \|\boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p}^{p} $$
Again, from **Lemma 2 (a)** we have that
$$ \|\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{b} \|_{p}^{p} \leqslant \big( \| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \big) \cdot \| \boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p}^{\frac{p}{q}}  $$
If $\|\boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p} = 0 $, then it's trivial. So let's assume that $\|\boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p} > 0$. Then we have that
$$  \| \boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p}^{p - \frac{p}{q}} \leqslant \big( \| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \big) \implies \| \boldsymbol{a + b} \|_{p} \leqslant \big( \| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \big) \quad \bigg[\text{as } p - \frac{p}{q} = 1\bigg] $$
Hence we have proved **Lemma 2 (a) & (b).**

$\blacksquare~$ With these we have that for $\boldsymbol{a} = (a_{1}, a_{2}, \dots, a_{n}) \in \mathbb{K}^n$

$\bullet~$ $\| \boldsymbol{a}\|_{p} \geqslant 0$ with equality when $\boldsymbol{a} = \boldsymbol{0}$.

$\bullet~$ For any $\lambda$ $\in \mathbb{K}$, we have  $$ \| \lambda \boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lvert \lambda a_{i}\rvert^{p}} = \lvert \lambda \rvert \sqrt[p]{\sum_{k = 1}^{n} \lvert a_{i}\rvert^{p}} = \lvert \lambda \rvert \|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} $$

$\bullet~$ The *Triangle Inequality* holds for any $\boldsymbol{b} = (b_{1}, b_{2},\dots, b_{n}) \in \mathbb{K}^n$, i.e.,
$$ \|\boldsymbol{a} + \boldsymbol{b} \|_{p} \leqslant \|\boldsymbol{a} \|_{p} + \|\boldsymbol{b} \|_{p}  $$

$ \bullet~ \bullet~ \bullet ~$ *Hence The map* $\| \cdot \|_{p} : \mathbb{K}^n \to \mathbb{R}_{0}$ *is a norm on* $\mathbb{K}^n$.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the details in the answer. But, I still won't understand from where $f(x)= x^{p-1}$ comes, is it an ansatz that we need in order to prove the inequality? Or is there an analytical proof for the development of this function that exists?

Comment: As I have explained, the proof of _Young's Inequality_ comes from the integration I've mentioned. Now to obtain the form $\frac{a^p}{p}$, we need the function $f(x) = x^{p - 1}$. I don't know about much Functional Analysis though, I'm just a first-year student  :)