# Let $f : [0, r) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ and $f \in \mathscr{C}^{0}$ and strictly increasing with $f(0) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, contest-math, solution-verification, integral-inequality

---

---

$\blacksquare~$ **Problem:** Let $f : [0, r) \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ and $f \in \mathscr{C}^{0}$ and strictly increasing with $f(0) = 0$ (the case of $r = \infty$ is allowed). Show that for every $a$ in $[0, r)$ and every $b$ in image of $[0, r)$ under $f$, we have
\begin{align*}
    ab \leqslant \int_{0}^{a} f(x) dx + \int_{0}^{b} f^{-1}(t) dt
\end{align*}

---

$\blacksquare~$ **My Approach:** We are given a function $f$ such that,
\begin{align*}
    f~:~[ 0 , r ) \rightarrow [ 0 , \infty )
\end{align*}
And also given $ f \in \mathscr{C}^{0} $ and strictly increasing with $ f ( 0 ) = 0$.

We also see that, $ f^{- 1} \in \mathscr{C}^0 $ and strictly increasing with $ f^{- 1} ( 0 ) = 0$ .

Now let us substitute $ f^{ - 1 } ( x )  $ by $u$ and obtain the following
\begin{align*}
        & f ( u ) = x\\
       \implies & f ' ( u ) du = dx 
\end{align*}

Therefore we obtain-

> - $x  \quad \quad \quad~~ 0 \quad \quad b  $

> - $f^{-1}(x) \quad  0 \quad \quad f^{- 1}(b) $

Now, let's observe that

- $f$ is strictly increasing and continuous on $[0, r)$ for any $r > 0$. Then $f$ is one-one.

Again, we have on substitution-
\begin{align*}
    & \int_{0}^{a} f ( x ) dx + \int_{0}^{f^{- 1} ( b )} u f' ( u ) du\\
        = ~ & \int_{0}^{a} f ( x ) dx + b f^{- 1} ( b ) + \int_{f^{- 1} ( b )}^{0}  f( u ) du\\
        = ~ & \int_{f^{- 1} ( b )}^{a} f ( x ) dx + b f^{- 1} ( b ) \\
        \geqslant ~ &  b f^{- 1} ( b )\\
        \geqslant ~ &  ba 
\end{align*}
As we have $ f ( a ) \leqslant b$ $\implies$ $a \leqslant f^{- 1} ( b ) ~$ [As $f^{- 1} $ is increasing ]

Hence we obtain our needed inequality.

---

$\S~$ **Target:** We'll basically prove **Young's Inequality** from here. I have proved it [earlier in a different way](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3765710/745108)

---

$\bullet~$ **Young's Inequality:** For $x, y > 0$ and $p, q > 1$ such that $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, then show that
\begin{align*}
    xy \leqslant \frac{x^{p}}{p} + \frac{y^{q}}{q} 
\end{align*}

---

$\bullet~$ **Extension from Last Problem:**  Given in problem,
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 \quad \text{Where } p , q   \in   ( 1 , \infty )
\end{align*}
Let us consider the function $ f $ defined as-
\begin{align*}
f~:~ &[0 , \infty ) \rightarrow [0 , \infty )\\
& x \mapsto x^{p - 1} \quad~ \text{ where } x \in \mathbb{R}^{+} 
\end{align*}
Such that the mapping is defined as following
\begin{align*}
 f ( x ) = x^{p - 1} \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
\end{align*}
Now observe that, $ f ( x ) $ is continuous, and strictly increasing in $(0 , \infty  )$ as,
\begin{align*}
f'(x) &= (p - 1)\cdot x^{p - 2} > 0 \quad \text{for any } x \in \mathbb{R}^{+}
\end{align*}
Now from our given fact about $ p ,q $ we obtain,
\begin{align*}
    &\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1\\
    \implies & \frac{1}{p} = \frac{q - 1}{ q }\\
    \implies &(p -1) = \frac{1}{(q - 1) }
\end{align*}
Therefore, we obtain the inverse mapping for the function given in question as-
\begin{align*}
f^{- 1} ( x ) & = x^{\frac{1}{( p - 1 )}} \\
&= x^{( q - 1 )}
\end{align*}
Therefore our function $f$ satisfies all the properties of the previous problem's function. Now from previous problem we have,
\begin{align*}
    & ab ~\leqslant~ \int_{0}^{a} f ( x ) dx + \int_{0}^{b} f^{- 1} ( y ) dy \\
    \Leftrightarrow ~ & ab ~\leqslant~ \int_{0}^{a} x^{( p - 1 )} dx + \int_{0}^{b} y^{( q - 1 )} dy \\
    \Leftrightarrow ~ & ab ~\leqslant~ \frac{a^p}{p} + \frac{b^{q}}{q}
\end{align*}
Which gives us our needed inequality.

---

---

Please check the proofs and claims for glitches and please add new ideas too :)

Comment: Why $f(a)\le b$?

Comment: If $f$ differentiable? Because you use $f'$.